# ROC curve vs. Spearman's rank correlation

Tags: roc, spearman-rho, auc

I have a dataset obtained by a psycholinguistic study. The participants perform a word identification task (i.e., they must say if each word corresponds to their language or not). The response accuracy may be 1 (correct) and 0 (incorrect). After each trial, there is a secondary task in which they need to judge their own performance. Therefore they need to report their perception on the primary task using three options:

1. I am sure, I did it right;
2. I am not sure;
3. I am sure I did it wrong.

My dataset looks like this:

[image]

I would like to get insight the relation between the Perception and the Response accuracy. What would be more appropriate to use, ROC curves or Spearman’s rank correlate?

Comment: Hm. In that they measure two completely different things? You could also ask in what way today's temperature and the diameter of my breakfast bagel differ. Could you edit you question to explain in more detail what you are interested in?

Comment: I apologize. I have edited the question. I hope it is specific enough now.

Comment: This is now clear enough, although the answer is going to be *neither*.

Comment: As a side note, the area under the ROC curve (concordance probability; $c$-index) is a simple translation of Somers' $D_{xy}$ rank correlation coefficient.

Answer (score 3):

Neither a ROC curve nor Spearman Correlation is the correct tool to use. I would first visualize this as a 3 by 2 table (3 for perception of accuracy and 2 for actual accuracy). Then do a chi-squared test to see if perception  of accuracy is actually evenly distributed within true accuracy or not. Assuming it is not, you can then proceed with a fisher exact test to test indivual groups. Note that for Chi-squared the sample size cannot be to small.